# Keep calling a function until a condition is met Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop, return

I want to create a hangman game. I want it to keep calling x and printing new_word until there is no "_". I have tried it but the slots keep refreshing. It keeps reprinting. It won't update the value itself.

```
word = 'EVAPORATE'
wordlist = list(word)
dict = dict(enumerate(wordlist))

slots = list('_' * len(word))

x = input("Guess the letter: ")

def game():    
    for a,b in dict.items():
        if b == x:
            slots[a] = x
            new_word = ' '.join(slots)
    print(new_word)

game()
```

Comment: Please follow this link i hope it will help you out https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/178312/another-python-hangman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
word = 'EVAPORATE'
wordlist = list(word)
dict = dict(enumerate(wordlist))
slots = list('_' * len(word))
def game():    
    while '_' in slots:
        x = input("Guess the letter: ")
        for a,b in dict.items():
            if b == x.upper():
                slots[a] = x
                new_word = ' '.join(slots)
        print(new_word)
game()
```

I have added in a `while` loop just inside `def game():` so that the code will keep running until slots has no underscores left in it. I then moved `x = input("Guess the letter: "` to inside the `while` loop so the user can always have another guess until the word is completed.

Answer (score 2):

A few things to add:

1. Don't you ever use keywords such as `list` or `dict` for variables
2. You have to count the matchs for each letter, example `E` appears twice, so, you have to count it twice
3. You have to know when the game ends, because you want to loop the question "guess letter" until the game ends
4. Add a While loop
5. Enjoy your game

---

```
word = 'EVAPORATE'
wordlist = list(word)
word_length = len(word)
word_dict = dict(enumerate(wordlist))

slots = list('_' * len(word))

def game():
  total_letters = word_length
  while not game_ended(total_letters):
    x = input("Guess the letter: ")
    matchs = 0
    for pos,letter in word_dict.items():
      if letter == x:
        matchs += 1
        slots[pos] = x
        new_word = ' '.join(slots)
    total_letters -= matchs
    print(new_word)

def game_ended(word_len):
  return word_len == 0
game()
```

Comment: I can't make the MD format as code, can somebody help me to edit my post?

Comment: Not sure why that worked, must have happened to me before using numbered lists.

Answer (score 0):

just put everything from the `input` until the end in a `while` loop

```py
word = 'EVAPORATE'
wordlist = list(word)

# it is not a good idea name a variable the same as a builtin, so change from 'dict' to 'worddict'
worddict = dict(enumerate(wordlist))

slots = list('_' * len(word))

def game(x):    
    # we also need to change it here
    for a,b in worddict.items():
        if b == x:
            slots[a] = x
            new_word = ' '.join(slots)
    print(new_word)

while any([i == '_' for i in slots]):
    x = input("Guess the letter: ")
    game(x)
```

the `while` check if any letter in `slots` is a `_`, if there is any, keep playing.

note that I also pass the `input` as a variable to game (it's not necessary, but it's better)